# redirect_uri containing query string does not match configured redirect URL's

Tags: oauth, office365, azure-active-directory

To be clear this question relates to v2.0 of the Azure AD API.

I've configured an allowed redirect url in the Application Registration Portal as `http://localhost:3000` (I've also tried `http://localhost:3000/_oauth/azureAd`).

Yet, when requesting an authorization code, providing a redirect_uri containing a query string causes authentication to fail with the error:
`The reply address 'http://localhost:3000/_oauth/azureAd?close' does not match the reply addresses configured for the application.`

It appears as though query strings are not ignored when matching a valid redirect URL. This is a problem as the Application Registration Portal won't allow you to enter redirect URL's with query strings!

I am in the process of writing an accounts package for Meteor to support v2.0 of Azure AD and this is a requirement for Meteor OAuth packages to function correctly.

The ideal solution I imagine is that query strings are ignored when validating redirect URL's

Answer (score 1):

The Application Registration Portal doesn't support the a query string and invalid special characters.

As a workaround, you may create several redirect URL instead of using the query string. But would you mind sharing the reason why you need to use the query string in URLs?

Comment: Thanks for your response, turns it out was a requirement with earlier versions of Meteor. Providing a configuration parameter removes the query string and in turn solves this problem!

Comment: Thanks Fei! What's the reason behind not supporting query parameters in the Redirect URL?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid Meteor appending `?close` to the redirect_uri by specifying a loginStyle configuration option. See: http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-loginWith

Explained here (snippet below): https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/abd574f38008b45f5e2a6bc322b10bcdde44763a/packages/oauth/oauth_common.js#L3-L8

```
  // XXX COMPAT WITH 0.9.0
  // The redirect URI used to have a "?close" query argument.  We
  // detect whether we need to be backwards compatible by checking for
  // the absence of the `loginStyle` field, which wasn't used in the
  // code which had the "?close" argument.
```